# Import database as factors or characters with package rodbc

Tags: r, rodbc

I am trying to read an MS Access database with the package("RODBC").

```
library("RODBC")
db<-file.path("file.accdb")
channel<-odbcConnectAccess2007(db)
dataSetName<-sqlFetch(channel,"file")
close(channel)
```

It works, but when I have numeric values starting by 0, for instance 089, the package reads it as integer and converts it in 89, it removes the zero. So, I would like to read the entire database as factors or characters to avoid this.
I was wondering if there is an argument to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: dataSetName<-sqlFetch(channel,"file", as.is=TRUE)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works well. Do you know if there are other possibilities to get the same with factors or others? How can I give you reputation for your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the entire database as characters (if possible):

```
dataSetName<-sqlFetch(channel,"file", as.is=TRUE)
```

For factors I am not completely sure. stringsAsFactors = TRUE might work.

```
dataSetName<-sqlFetch(channel,"file", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the second one is to import characters as factors.